# Cannot resolve symbol in Grails project

Tags: grails, groovy, spring-security

I am using Spring Security core on this Grails project. I get the error "password" cannot be resolve in the BootStrap class.

I have this domain class:

```
class Person {

transient springSecurityService

String realName
String username
String password
boolean enabled
boolean accountExpired
boolean accountLocked
boolean passwordExpired

static constraints = {
    username blank: false, unique: true
    password blank: false
}

static mapping = {
    password column: '`password`'
}

Set<Authority> getAuthorities() {
    PersonAuthority.findAllByPerson(this).collect { it.authority } as Set
}

def beforeInsert() {
    encodePassword()
}

def beforeUpdate() {
    if (isDirty('password')) {
        encodePassword()
    }
}

protected void encodePassword() {
    password = springSecurityService.encodePassword(password)
}
}
```

and this is my BootsStrap class:

```
class BootStrap {




def init = { servletContext ->

    if (!Person.count()) {
        createData()
    }
}
def destroy = {
}

private void createData() {
    def userRole = new Authority(authority: 'ROLE_USER').save()



    [harry: 'Harry Brock'].each { userName, realName ->
        def user = new Person(username: userName, realName: realName, password: password, enabled: true).save()
        PersonAuthority.create user, userRole, true
    }
}
}
```

I am using Grails 2.2 and Spring Security Core 1.2.7.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within BootStrap you are using a undefined variable named `password`.

I added a comment above the line with the problem:

```
[harry: 'Harry Brock'].each { userName, realName ->
  // userName and realName are closure parameters, enabled is always true.. but where is password defined?
  def user = new Person(username: userName, realName: realName, password: password, enabled: true).save()
  PersonAuthority.create user, userRole, true
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to set the password to password. I did it by doing this: password: "password"

Answer (score 0):

All these properties can not be null when you instantiate an User object:

```
String password        //apparently it missed, but the other 3 are also needed
boolean accountExpired
boolean accountLocked
boolean passwordExpired
```

So save the userInstance like this:

```
def user = new Person(username: userName, realName: realName, password: password, enabled: true, accountExpired:false, accountLocked:false, passwordExpired:false).save()
```

Or, you can put there boolean properties in beforeInsert() to simplify your code:

```
def beforeInsert() {
    enabled=true
    accountExpired=false
    accountLocked=false
    passwordExpired=false
    encodePassword()
}
```